# How to create more complex SQL queries from Controller

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

First of all, let me say that I don't know that the current issue is the "correct" way to get what I want.  Here's the problem.

I have a database named `users` that looks like this:

```
|__id__|__dateTime__|___ipAddress___|__userName__|
|   1  |   time1    |  192.168.0.1  |  Paul      |
|   2  |   time2    |  192.168.0.22 |  Jessica   |
|   3  |   time1    |  192.168.0.22 |  Jon       |
```

I know that in the Controller, I can write things like

```
User.find(3)
```

and that's the equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (users.id = 3) LIMIT 1
```

But, what if, in my logs, I want to do something like finding how many unique ip addresses there are, or if I want a query that returns how many events happened during `time1`.

Is there a way to do this in the Controller, or is this not where something like that should be done?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Record offers a query interface, which can be [found on the guides here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). You can execute [arbitrary queries as well](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql) with #find_by_query, and don't need to depend on helper methods.

> finding how many unique ip addresses

this would be accomplished with something like
`User.select(:ipAddress).distinct.count`

> I want a query that returns how many events happened during time1

I'm not sure what you mean by events, but if you want a count of the entries in the User table that match a given timestamp, you can do `User.where(:dateTime=>time1).count`

(I assume your given example is fake, but you wouldn't want to name a column dateTime)